# How to extract a vector element without using the index

Tags: r, vector, indexing

I have this vector containing names of different countries:

```
Contries<-c("United States", "India", "Brazil", "France", "Mali", "Australia")
```

I want to extract only "`France`", then I want to extract all country names except the `France`, without using the index of `France`, but the name of France itself.

I tried these but they don't work.

```
Contries["France"]
Contries[!"France"]
```

Finally, I want to extract the names of all countries except `France` and `Mali`

```
Contries[!c("France","Mali")]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
> Contries[-match(c("France", "Mali"), Contries)]
[1] "United States" "India"         "Brazil"        "Australia"
```

Answer (score 3):

```r
Contries[!Contries %in% c("France", "Mali")]
#> [1] "United States" "India"         "Brazil"        "Australia"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

```
Contries<-c("United States", "India", "Brazil", "France", "Mali", "Australia")
```

Include

```
Contries[Contries == "France"]
```

Exclude single element

```
Contries[Contries != "France"]
```

Exclude multiple elements

```
Contries[!Contries %in% c("France, Mali")]
Contries[Contries %in% setdiff(Contries, c("France", "Mali"))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Although a little more code, you can also do this with `dplyr`.

Include

```
library(dplyr)
country <-
  as.data.frame(Contries) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Contries == "France") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as.character()
```

Exclude single element

```
country <-
  as.data.frame(Contries) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Contries != "France") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as.character()
```

Exclude multiple elements

```
country <-
   as.data.frame(Contries) %>% 
   dplyr::filter(!Contries %in% c("France", "Mali")) %>% 
   unlist() %>% 
   as.character()
```